# Regression analysis with non-integer event rates

Tags: regression, data-imputation

I am working as part of a team on a large dataset which has been subject to imputation analysis.

One of my colleagues has pointed out that the when carrying out regressions that can provide odds ratio/event ratios etc, we first need to have the event rates from each variable in integer form. However, because of the imputation analysis we have been left with non-integer data for many variables. For example, our imputed data shows that 72.1/401 of our participants were in a relationship.

My questions are as follows:

1. Is it indeed the case that event rate/frequencies need to be in integer form before regression analysis can be run?
2. If this is the case, can we (either manually or through the use of an SPSS function) adjust the data to correct this issue?

I am aware that there is a function for doing as part of the imputation analysis, however re-running the imputation analysis is something we would like to avoid.Also, in case it’s relevant, it’s primarily logistic regressions that we will be running, though we may also use linear regression as well.

Finally, I’d just like to point out that I’m not particularly comfortable imputing categorical variables such as the one mentioned above, but this was a decision made by others in my team.

Comment: You don't need events as integers unless you model them as Poisson or other discrete distribution directly. If you're modeling odds ratios or frequencies as probabilities, the variables will not be integer for sure.

Comment: So, just to be clear, I can just run regressions in the same way as I always would without having to worry about this?

To be honest, I wasn't sure why this would be an issue, but it was my colleague (who is more experienced than I) who proposed that it would be an issue

Comment: An example where you need count data: your regression models counts directly and the error distribution is Poisson, i.e. your dependent variable is counts. On the other hand if you convert counts into probabilities or ratios before modeling, then you don't worry about integers.

Comment: Thanks Aksakalm, that's really useful, I'll look in to the second method you've mentioned. Much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of kinds of regression. When you have count data, you ought to be using a count model (Poisson or negative binomial or some such) regression, particularly if the counts are small or if there are only a few of them.  That is, when your dependent variable is a non-negative integer

However, you don't say you have count data, you say you have rate data. Rates do not need to be (and usually are not) integers. 72/401 is not an integer, just as 72.1/401 is not.

You can still have odds ratios (or any other measure) if you do not have integers.

I hope the above helps; it may not, because I am not entirely clear what you are trying to do.  What exactly is your dependent variable and what form of regression are you trying to run?

Comment: Thanks for your response Peter.

There a lot of different things we are looking into but I'll give you one example of this.

Overall we are interested in the impact that things such as relationships, or the type of health services used, can have on the life of individuals with severe learning difficulties.

So, one type of analysis we might run would be a logistic regression looking at employment where 0 = unemployed and 1 = employed. Our IV's in this case would be age, gender, where the individual lives, whether or not the individual was in a relationship etc.

Comment: If the dependent variable is a dichotomy, then you should not impute fractional values. I doubt you should impute the DV at all; you might want to add "missing" as a third category, especially if a lot of people are missing for that variable.  You can impute the independent variables and the method should vary for categorical and continuous variables.

Comment: Thanks again, I agree that categorical variables shouldn't be imputed at all, unfortunately this decision was out of my control. Though when the imputation was run, it was certainly the case that categorical and continuous variables were treated differently.

Putting that to the side, I assume then that for continuous variables, there is no problem with running a regression in the usual way with a dataset that has been imputed? (even if the frequencies associated with events include decimal points, rather than being 'whole numbers')

Thanks again

Comment: No, you misunderstood what I said.  You can certainly impute categorical independent variables.

Comment: You can use a Poisson rate regression with a quasipoisson family function (in R speek.)